# Determine the size of time_t with preprocessor?

Tags: c++, sizeof, c-preprocessor

Is there a way to know the size of `time_t` at the time the preprocessor is running?

I'd like to know whether `time_t` is an `int32_t` or `int64_t` and I'd like the trick to work under Linux (POSIX) and Windows (and if possible under Mac OS/X). It'd like it early on so I can do something like this:

```
#if time_t == _32BIT
typedef zint32_t my_time_t;
#else
typedef zint64_t my_time_t;
#endif
```

My `zint32/64_t` types are automatically initialized to zero. That works great for most types, but it is problematic with `time_t` at this point. Unless I can determine the size at compile time with the preprocessor.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no standard macro to detect the size of `time_t`, and you cannot compute the size of a type during preprocessing (since "types" do not exist during preprocessing).  You can, however, achieve your desired result using templates:

```
#include <ctime>
#include <utility>

typedef std::conditional<
    sizeof(time_t) == 8,
    zint64_t,
    zint32_t
>::type my_time_t;
```

Do note that `sizeof(time_t)` is implementation-defined and may be something other than four or eight bytes.  You'll need to be sure to account for this, either by ensuring that on all of your target platforms it is either four or eight bytes, or by adding additional logic to handle other sizes.

Comment: I swear I need to stop reinventing `std::conditional`.